# Exception issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, exception

All the time, to avoid any run time error, I use the Exception handler:

as the following:

```
try
{
    //My code which may raise an error.
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
            string message = ee.Message;
            ShowMessage();
}
```

---

My question is:

1. **Is** this considered as a good practice or bad practice? (I use the same
   lines all the time)
2. What about the performance issue every time declaring a string?
3. **When** using those lines with a method which return a value, the
   returning must be after the catch?

Comment: You should search a bit here on SO there are countless examples on exception handling and best practices. And your `message` is rather useless if you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general structure of exception handling is the following:

```
try
{
    //do struff here
}
catch (...)
{
    //handle exception here
}
finally
{
    //clean up here
}
```

There are a couple of things to note in your code that are not entirely right (they are terrible in fact :p):

1. Only catch exceptions you are ready to handle and do not handle those you are not. This means that you should only catch particular exceptions (`FileNotFoundException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, whatever) that you know *can* happen in exceptional cases (never use exception handling as a normal execution flow tool). Catching `System.Exception` is considered bad practice (unless it is for logging purposes and you `throw;` immeadiately afterwards) because this `exception` can be thrown by any darn thing, which with all probability you have not foreseen when writing your code and therefore have no clue on how to handle it correctly.
2. Depending on your situation you should consider using `finally` blocks in order to clean up whatever you can before exiting the method (be it because of normal execution flow, or an unhandled exception). Note that `finally` blocks will be (normally) always executed before exiting the method scope.
3. Do not swallow exceptions and the information they contain. You should consider logging it somewhere (myApplication.log file) and show the user a more friendly *"we have aproblem"* message. Otherwise the only information you will have when bugs crop up in production will be whatever you show the user. All the valuable information stored in the caught `exception` will be lost.

Comment: but what if any run time error, i don't put in my consideration does happen, the error will appear to the user ??!! in a bad context way.

Comment: @just_name: You should log the error, show a friendly message to the user and then exit the program. You should not continue the execution of your code when an exception you have not planned for is thrown. Your application has no idea how to handle that situation so it is better fo quitting as gracefully as possible.

Comment: With regard to point (1), how should one deal with the fact that a statemelt like "SomeObject=SomeClass.LoadFromFile(userSpecifiedFilename)" might have any number of things go wrong with it, the extremely vast majority of which mean "The system isn't on fire, but SomeObject didn't get loaded".  I don't really like the idea of using a catch-all exception handler, but I also don't like the idea of trying to figure out everything that the load routine might throw, and having the whole application die because the routine threw something like a ThumbdriveRemovedException which I didn't anticipate.

Comment: @supercat: documentation of `SomeClass` and specifically of the method `LoadFromFile` should enumerate the exceptions thrown by said method. It is up to you to decide which you want to handle and where. If `SomeClass` is in your project then you *should* know what possible exceptions can be raised if something goes wrong specific to the method. I really do not think the amount of exceptions amount to too many in most cases.

Comment: It is true that in some cases it can be tedious but I see no way around it. IMHO, you should not handle, or log and continue when an exception you really know nothing about is thrown. I would recommend when faced with scenarios of methods with numerous potential exceptions to use helper methods that encapsulate the method call and the exception handling.

Comment: @InBetween: If there is a static list of functions that can be called, then one might endeavor to determine all the exceptions they could throw, but even in the static case enumerating all possibilities is a lot of work.  Add in things like inversion of control and things get even harder.  I find it really annoying that there's no useful hierarchy among the standard exceptions to distinguish "The system isn't on fire, but the operation didn't happen" from "The system is on fire".  Microsoft may discourage custom exceptions, but IMHO conventions recommending their use would help...

Comment: @InBetween: ...people more narrowly determine whether exceptions should be caught.  As it is, if I call LoadAcmeDocument and I get a FileNotFound error, I can't really be sure, except by examining the stack trace, whether it was document or something else couldn't be found, or what I should do about it.  If LoadAcmeDocument threw an AcmeDocumentLoadFailureException whenever it couldn't load for any reason vaguely foreseeable to the author of the AcmeDocument class, a user of the AcmeDocument class could distinguish expected from unexpected failures.

Comment: @InBetween: Of course, if AcmeDocument.LoadAcmeDocument catches an OutOfMemoryException and rethrows as an AcmeDocumentLoadFailureException, that probably won't be very helpful, but I'm not really sure what to do about that.  While it may be that the author of the client code is more conscientious with exceptions than the author of AcmeDocument, there's no reason to expect him to know more about which exceptions simply mean the document didn't load, and which indicate bigger problems.

Comment: @supercat: You are absolutely right about there not being in some cases a reasonable hierarchy in the standard exceptions. And it is also true that you have no control on whether third party code is handling exceptions as they should be. Still, I do not think that because of these shortcomings you should not implement your code the *right* way. I am not aware that Microsoft is discouraging custom exceptions (link?) (I know they deprecated ApplicationException because it had no added value). IMHO custom exceptions are the only way to create a useful exception hierarchy in your code.

Answer (score 6):

That's bad code. Actually *very* bad.

As all you do with the error message is to assign it to a string that you never use, you are effectively just catching the exception and ignoring it. This is pretty much the worst thing that you can do with an exception, as the program will continue on as if nothing happened, likely with unusable or corrupted data.

When catching exceptions:

- Use a more specific Exception type, for example SqlException or IOException, so that you only capture the exceptions that you intend to catch, and that you know how to handle.
- When catching an exception, either really handle it, or rethrow it so that it can be handled at a different level.

Comment: but what if any run time error, i don't put in my consideration does happen, the error will appear to the user ??!! in a bad context way.

Comment: @just_name: That is the type of exception that you should handle on the application level. For a web application that is the page that handles unhandled exceptions. You can specify in web.config what page to show to the user when that happens.

Answer (score 4):

You should handle known issues first to improve performance, such as null references, empty strings, etc.

Use exceptions for *exceptional* cases.

Declaring the `string` isn't a bad thing in there, but its not doing anything other than holding another reference.

You can safely return from a `try` block. But as Damokles states, you should also have another return else where.

Comment: But he needs a default return either in finally or after the try block.

Comment: thanks a lot,but when i put the return in the `try` block , it gives me a compiler error , `not all code pathes return a value`.

Answer (score 1):

You should only catch exceptions that you are expecting and know how to handle them. by `catch (Exception)` you are catching all kind of exceptions in a method is not a good practice.

You can catch all exceptions to just log them or restart you application on fail..

For example

```
try
{
    //My code which may raise an error.
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)//you are expecting this exception
{
    //handle file not found here.
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    string message = ee.Message;
    Log(message);
    throw;//rethrow the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add exception handler in all the functions. Add the exception handling at the main() which wraps all the functions. Only add exceptions handlers at place where you intend to do some specific exception handling operation to prevent the application from crash.

Return value can be added in the try block.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing this to IGNORE exceptions? In that case you can do it like this:

```
try
{
// code
}
catch {}
```

This will catch all exceptions and do nothing with them(ignore).

I would however not recommend doing that, because you will now never know why some functionality in your system is not working as expected because no errors are thrown. I would then recommend at the minimum at least LOG the exception so that you can troubleshoot problems later. A better approach would be to log the exception and re-throw it and then have friendly exception handling at the UI layer.

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a **bad practice** as you basically ignore the exception. You don't even show it to the user!

It's even double bad, because it is also a bad practice to copy-paste the same lines all over your code.

Recommended usage is to either **handle** the exception, **or do not touch** it at all. As it's rather uncommon that the code knows how to handle an exception, the common case is to not catch it at all!

Of course, way up in your main loop, you'll have a try-catch, which will log the exception and/or report the exception to the user.

With respect to your second question: Yes, a return statement can be part of the catch block. But if you don't know what to return, you should not catch the exception!